numpy 2d arrays, remove duplicate rows
I have 2 2d numpy arrays, Array A and Array B.
I want to remove rows who occurs in both arrays for Array A and B.
But, if it occurs 1 time in Array A and 2 times in Array B, I want to only remove it 1 time in both Arrays.
If it occurs for 5 times in Array A and 3 times in Array B, I want it to be removed 3 times in both Arrays.
Thanks

do you mean to say I want to remove elements  instead of arrays?

sorry, I meant rows. I changed the question, thanks !

Please be explicit, provide a meaningful [mre] to clearly demonstrate the expected logic

You can convert the rows to tuples (so they can be hashed), use a Counter dictionary instance to count the number of rows from each matrix, convert the keys of each dictionary to sets, find common rows, remove the appropriate value from each counter dictionary, then reconstruct the matrices.
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

def custom_remove_duplicates(matrix1, matrix2):
    rows1 = [tuple(row) for row in matrix1.tolist()]
    rows2 = [tuple(row) for row in matrix2.tolist()]

    counter1 = Counter(rows1)
    counter2 = Counter(rows2)

    common_rows = set(counter1.keys()) & set(counter2.keys())

    for row in common_rows:
        min_count = min(counter1[row], counter2[row])
        counter1[row] -= min_count
        counter2[row] -= min_count

    new_matrix1_list = [list(row) for row in counter1.elements()]
    new_matrix2_list = [list(row) for row in counter2.elements()]

    new_matrix1 = np.array(new_matrix1_list)
    new_matrix2 = np.array(new_matrix2_list)

    return new_matrix1, new_matrix2


This is more or less my first approach here except I first got a unique identifier to use as key in the Counter (to avoid having to repeatedly hash multiple columns).

Assuming these two arrays as example:
A = np.array([[0,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[0,0]])
B = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]])

You could count the unique rows in each array, compute the difference of counts (here using collections.Counter as helper) and recreate the wanted arrays with indexing and repeat.
from collections import Counter

# combine the two arrays and count the values
# combining the arrays ensures to have the same IDs
u, inv, cnt = np.unique(np.vstack([A, B]), axis=0,
                        return_inverse=True,
                        return_counts=True)

# get the counts for A only
uA, cntA = np.unique(inv[:len(A)], return_counts=True)

# total counts per unique row
c = Counter(dict(zip(range(len(u)), cnt)))
# Counter({2: 4, 1: 3, 3: 3, 0: 1})

# counts of A per unique row
cA = Counter(dict(zip(uA, cntA)))
# Counter({1: 2, 0: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1})

# not directly needed but we could count the unique B
# cB = c-cA
# Counter({2: 3, 3: 2, 1: 1})

final_A = cA+cA-c  # = cA - cB = cA - (c-cA)
# Counter({0: 1, 1: 1})
final_B = c-cA-cA  # = cB - cA = (c-cA) - cA
# Counter({2: 2, 3: 1})

outA = u[np.repeat(list(final_A), list(final_A.values()))]
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]])

outB = u[np.repeat(list(final_B), list(final_B.values()))]
# array([[1, 0],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1]])

Using pandas
De-duplicate the rows and a merge with indicator=True, then identify the unique rows from A or B with left_only/right_only:
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
cols = list(dfA)

out = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, how='outer', indicator=True,
               left_on=cols+[dfA.groupby(cols).cumcount()],
               right_on=cols+[dfB.groupby(cols).cumcount()]
              )

outA = out.query('_merge == "left_only"')[cols].to_numpy()
# array([[0, 0],
#        [0, 1]])

outB = out.query('_merge == "right_only"')[cols].to_numpy()
# array([[1, 0],
#        [1, 0],
#        [1, 1]])

Intermediate after the merge:
   0  1  key_2      _merge
0  0  0      0   left_only
1  0  1      0        both
2  0  1      1   left_only
3  1  0      0        both
4  1  0      1  right_only
5  1  0      2  right_only
6  1  1      0        both
7  1  1      1  right_only


ar = []
br = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if not i in ar:
        for j in range(len(b)):
            if not j in br:
                if np.array_equal(a[i], b[j]):
                    ar.append(i)
                    br.append(j)
a = np.delete(a, ar, 0)
b = np.delete(b, br, 0)

